# Filter at multiple levels with GraphQL and Graphene

Tags: python, django, graphql

I'm using Django and Graphene and have multiple levels I'd like to filter on.  But I can't get past either "Unknown operation named \"undefined\"." or getting ALL objects at each level of the hierarchy (i.e.: ALL jobDetails for all jobs listed for EACH job).

I'm trying to do this query:

```
query {
  allPushes(revision: "1ef73669e8fccac35b650ff81df1b575a39a0fd5") {
    edges {
      node {
        revision
        author
        jobs (result: "testfailed") {
          edges {
            node {
              result
              jobDetails (url_Iendswith: "errorsummary.log") {
                edges {
                  node {
                    url
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In Django, `jobDetails` has a foreign key to `jobs`, which has a foreign key to `pushes`

My first attempt was to setup my nodes:

```
class JobDetailNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = JobDetail
        filter_fields = {
            'url': ('exact', 'icontains', 'iendswith')
        }
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )


class JobNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        filter_fields = ('result', 'tier')
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

    job_details = DjangoFilterConnectionField(JobDetailNode)


class PushNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Push
        filter_fields = ('revision', )
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

    jobs = DjangoFilterConnectionField(JobNode)
```

But this returns, as I said, all `jobDetails` at for EACH job, not just the jobDetails that belong to that job.

But if I remove those `DjangoFilterConnectionField` fields, then I can't filter at each level; just the first.

My Query looks like this:

```
class Query(ObjectType):
    all_pushes = DjangoFilterConnectionField(PushNode)
    all_jobs = DjangoFilterConnectionField(JobNode)
    all_job_details = DjangoFilterConnectionField(JobDetailNode)

    def resolve_all_pushes(self, args):
        return Push.objects.filter(**args)

    def resolve_all_jobs(self, args):
        return Job.objects.filter(**args)

    def resolve_all_job_details(self, args):
        return JobDetail.objects.filter(**args)
```

Any suggestions on how to setup filtering at multiple levels like this?  Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in graphene-django. It was fixed in version 1.3.
[Changelog](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/releases)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the same person asked the question on [graphene github](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/445) page, but it looks almost, if not exactly the same. Apart from the fact mentioned bug existed, you still need some improvement in your code.

In order to make it work as you described (getting only related `JobDetail` for each `Job`) you have to define a resolver inside `JobNode`:

```
def resolve_job_details(self, args, context, info):
    return JobDetail.objects.filter(job=self, **args)
```

Of course you need also `Job` resolver inside `PushNode`:

```
def resolve_jobs(self, args, context, info):
    return Job.objects.filter(push=self, **args)
```